# Regular expression to return text between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
u'abcde(date=\'2/xc2/xb2\',time=\'/case/test.png\')'
```

All I need is the contents inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Why not use double quotes? It would make the string easier to read, i.e. `u"abcde(date='2/xc2/xb2',time='/case/test.png')"`

Comment: This question makes me nervous just looking at it.  I get the sneaking suspicion OP *really* wants the functionality in `ast` and just doesn't know it exists.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

If your problem is really just this simple, you don't need regex:

```
s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
```

Comment: what if there is no '(' and ')'? you will get s[0:-1]. Which means you will get whatever in 's' :\. It will be good if you check that the string has parenthesis first.

Comment: What if you'll have "(some text (some text in inner parenthesis) some more text)"?

Comment: Then the problem is not as simple as the original problem and will require a different solution.

Comment: For Igor's question: if you have nested parenthesis like that, you use rfind for the second part of the operation. See my post below for more details on this.

Comment: sometimes people forget basic stuff, falling into trap of using complex solutions with regex. (I'm one of them btw).

Answer (score 101):

Use `re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',s).group(1)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'abcde(date=\'2/xc2/xb2\',time=\'/case/test.png\')'
>>> re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',s).group(1)
u"date='2/xc2/xb2',time='/case/test.png'"
```

Answer (score 83):

If you want to find all occurrences:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\(.*?\)", s)
[u"(date='2/xc2/xb2',time='/case/test.png')", u'(eee)']

>>> re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)", s)
[u"date='2/xc2/xb2',time='/case/test.png'", u'eee']
```

Comment: might be a stupid question, but why is the "?" needed ? Why does "\(.*\)" not work?

Comment: @CutePoison because `.*` is greedy (will take the longest match) and `.*?` is not greedy (will take the shortest match)

Comment: this does not work.... you have to add .* before and after       like     r".*\((.*?)\).*"

Comment: @zdanman, it works fine for me even without adding `.*`.

Answer (score 39):

Building on tkerwin's answer, if you happen to have **nested parentheses** like in

```
st = "sum((a+b)/(c+d))"
```

his answer will not work if you need to take everything between the ***first* opening parenthesis** and the ***last* closing parenthesis** to get `(a+b)/(c+d)`, because find searches from the left of the string, and would stop at the first closing parenthesis.

To fix that, you need to use `rfind` for the second part of the operation, so it would become

```
st[st.find("(")+1:st.rfind(")")]
```

Comment: @ALH that expression does not have **nested** parenthesis, which is what my answer is good for.

Answer (score 10):

```
import re

fancy = u'abcde(date=\'2/xc2/xb2\',time=\'/case/test.png\')'

print re.compile( "\((.*)\)" ).search( fancy ).group( 1 )
```

Answer (score 7):

```
contents_re = re.match(r'[^\(]*\((?P<contents>[^\(]+)\)', data)
if contents_re:
    print(contents_re.groupdict()['contents'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: This worked like a charm including newline. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

TheSoulkiller's answer is great. just in my case, I needed to handle extra parentheses and only extract the word inside the parentheses. a very small change would solve the problem

```
>>> s=u'abcde((((a+b))))-((a*b))'
>>> re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)
['(((a+b', '(a*b']
>>> re.findall('\(+(.*?)\)',s)
['a+b', 'a*b']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways to extract strings between parentheses in Pandas with the `\(([^()]+)\)` regex (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZxmxR9/1)) that matches

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]+)` - then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

**Extracting the first occurrence** using [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['some text (value 1) and (value 2)']})
df['Values'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\(([^()]+)\)')
# => df['Values']
#    0    value 1
#    Name: Values, dtype: object
```

**Extracting (finding) all occurrences** using [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['some text (value 1) and (value 2)']})
df['Values'] = df['Description'].str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)')
# => df['Values']
#    0    [value 1, value 2]
#    Name: Values, dtype: object

df['Values'] = df['Description'].str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)').str.join(', ')
# => df['Values']
#    0    value 1, value 2
#    Name: Values, dtype: object
```

Note that `.str.join(', ')` is used to create a comma-separated string out of the resulting list of strings. You may adjust this separator for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If im not missing something, a small fix to @tkerwin:
s[s.find("(")+1:s.rfind(")")]

The 2nd find should be rfind so you start search from end of string

Answer (score -1):

testcase

```
s = "(rein<unint>(pBuf) +fsizeof(LOG_RECH))"
```

result

```
['pBuf', 'LOG_RECH', 'rein<unint>(pBuf) +fsizeof(LOG_RECH)']
```

implement

```
def getParenthesesList(s):
    res = list()
    left = list()
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '(':
            left.append(i)
        if s[i] == ')':
            le = left.pop()
            res.append(s[le + 1:i])
    print(res)
    return res
```