# Copy text between parentheses in pandas DataFrame column into another column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to copy text that appears between parentheses in a pandas DataFrame column into another column. I have come across this solution to parse strings accordingly: [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/python-regex-help-return-text-between-parenthesis)

I would like to assign the result element-by-element to the same row in a new column. 
However, this doesn't carry over directly to pandas Series. I seems that map/apply/lambda seems the way to go. I've arrived at this piece of code, but getting an invalid syntax error.

```
dataSources.dataUnits = dataSources.dataDescription.map(str.find("(")+1:str.find(")"))
```

Obviously, I'm not yet fluent enough there - help much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just use an apply with the same method suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894156/1240268):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['hi(pandas)there'])

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0    hi(pandas)there
dtype: object

In [13]: s.apply(lambda st: st[st.find("(")+1:st.find(")")])
Out[13]:
0    pandas
dtype: object
```

Or perhaps you could use one of the Series string methods e.g. [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
In [14]: s.str.replace(r'[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*', '')
Out[14]:
0    pandas
dtype: object
```

*throw away all the stuff before the `(` and all the stuff after `)` inclusive.*

From 0.13 you can use the [extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) method:

```
In [15]: s.str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*')
Out[15]: 
0    pandas
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just one question: rows without parenthesized content return the entire field (fields are enclosed by ''). How to avoid this / skip rows where there is nothing to be found?

Comment: Hmm not too sure, think you may be better off just with the apply, but something using match could be possible: `s.str.findall(r'(?<=\()[^(]*(?=\))')`

Comment: The issue came up with apply in fact. Findall works! Last thing - how do I get rid of the square brackets around the results other than stripping them after the fact?

Comment: @AndyHayden what if we want to get only digits from bracket values i.e. "Titanic (1997) (Drama)" . It is giving me Drama instead of 1997. I want to extract only year. How can I do that??

Comment: @MegaBytes maybe use \d+ rather than [^(]*

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden I used this one which works for me `data['Title'].str.extract('.*\((.*\d{4})\).*')`