# Extract/Substring data of variable length from Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as follows:

```
df
   title     TestData  Value 
0      A  Test1(data)    1.0 
1      B     t(data2)    2.2 
2      C   Ts(data 3)    3.3
```

I want to extract from the entire `TestData` column the data within parenthesis as follows:

```
   title  TestData  Value 
0      A      data    1.0 
1      B     data2    2.2 
2      C    data 3    3.3
```

The index of the parenthesis keeps changing so does the length of the string within parenthesis. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842001/copy-text-between-parentheses-in-pandas-dataframe-column-into-another-column

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['TestData'] = df['TestData'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)", expand=False)
print (df)
  title TestData  Value
0     A     data    1.0
1     B    data2    2.2
2     C   data 3    3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can using `str.split`

```
df.TestData=df.TestData.str.split(pat='[(|)]',expand=True)[1]
df
Out[129]: 
  TestData  Value title
0     data      1     A
1    data2      2     B
2   data 3      3     C
```