# Extract substring between two characters in pandas

Tags: pandas, substring, extract

I have a column containing strings in this format:

```
/* [MCCOOK 0     ] */,999990,'MCCOOK  0   '
```

I want to extract the substring between [ and ] into another column. Please advise.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842576/9754169 you can use the `apply` approach

```
your_column.apply(lambda st: st[st.find("[")+1:st.find("]")])
```