# How in Pandas Dataframe and Python can extract the specific text string after a given word?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract the text inside the range "text: ....." from this dataframe and create another column with that value.

This is my Pandas Dataframe

[image]

```
issues_df['new_column'] = issues_df['fields.description.content'].apply(lambda x: x['text'])
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
issues_df['new_column'] = issues_df['fields.description.content'].apply(lambda x: x['text'])
TypeError: Object 'float' is not writable.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: the column values are list not object try to change `x["text"]` to `x[0]["content"][0]["text"]`

Comment: perhaps this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660357/extract-substring-between-two-characters-in-pandas/51660658#51660658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `NaN` in column, you can try `.str` accessor

```py
issues_df['new_column'] = issues_df['fields.description.content'].str[0].str['content'].str[0].str['text']
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be a good task for the rather efficient [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```py
df['new_column'] = pd.json_normalize(
    df['fields.description.content'], 'content'
)['text']
```