# Parsing a string into a list of dicts

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, data-structures, string-parsing

I have a string that looks like this:

`POLYGON ((148210.445767647 172418.761192525, 148183.930888667 172366.054787545, 148183.866770629 172365.316772032, 148184.328078148 172364.737139913, 148220.543522168 172344.042601933, 148221.383518338 172343.971823159), (148221.97916844 172344.568316375, 148244.61381946 172406.651932395, 148244.578100039 172407.422441673, 148244.004662562 172407.938319453, 148211.669446582 172419.255646473, 148210.631989339 172419.018894911, 148210.445767647 172418.761192525))`

I can easily strip `POLYGON` out of the string to focus on the numbers but I'm kinda wondering what would be the easiest/best way to parse this string into a list of dict.

The first parenthesis (right after POLYGON) indicates that multiple elements can be provided (separated by a comma `,`).

So each pair of numbers is to supposed to be `x` and `y`.

I'd like to parse this string to end up with the following data structure (using `python 2.7`):

```
list [ //list of polygons
  list [ //polygon n°1
    dict { //polygon n°1's first point
      'x': 148210.445767647, //first number
      'y': 172418.761192525 //second number
    },
    dict { //polygon n°1's second point
      'x': 148183.930888667,
      'y': 148183.930888667
    },
    ... // rest of polygon n°1's points
  ], //end of polygon n°1
  list [ // polygon n°2
    dict { // polygon n°2's first point
      'x': 148221.9791684,
      'y': 172344.568316375
    },
    ... // rest of polygon n°2's points
  ] // end of polygon n°2
] // end of list of polygons
```

Polygons' number of points is virtually infinite.
Each point's numbers are separated by a blank.

Do you guys know a way to do this in a loop or any recursive way ?

PS: I'm kind of a python beginner (only a few months under my belt) so don't hesitate to explain in details. Thank you!

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind is using the substring mechanism like `string[xx:xx]` over and over again together with `string.index('character')` but I've seen so many pretty solutions from python devs on SO that I believe there must be a prettier solution than this. I'm not asking for people to actually do the work for me, but a lead or two would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try?

```
import ast

POLYGON = '((148210.445767647 172418.761192525, 148183.930888667 172366.054787545, 148183.866770629 172365.316772032, 148184.328078148 172364.737139913, 148220.543522168 172344.042601933, 148221.383518338 172343.971823159), (148221.97916844 172344.568316375, 148244.61381946 172406.651932395, 148244.578100039 172407.422441673, 148244.004662562 172407.938319453, 148211.669446582 172419.255646473, 148210.631989339 172419.018894911, 148210.445767647 172418.761192525))'
new_polygon = '(' + POLYGON.replace(', ', '),(').replace(' ', ',') + ')'


data = ast.literal_eval(new_polygon)
result_list = list()
for items in data:
    sub_list = list()
    for item in items:
        sub_list.append({
            'x': item[0],
            'y': item[1]
        })
    result_list.append(sub_list)

print result_list
```

Comment: It is much safer to use `ast.literal_eval` than `eval`.

Comment: I added `POLYGON.replace('POLYGON ', '')` on line 3 and was able to make this work perfectly (with my string starting with `POLYGON ((123...`. Thanks a lot @GWW and @mccakici.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you have defining your Polygon object looks very similar to a python tuple declaration.  One option, albeit a bit hacky would be to use python's [AST parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

You would have to strip off the POLYGON part and this solution may not work for other declarations that are more complex.

```
import ast
your_str = "POLYGON (...)"
# may be better to use a regex to split off the class part 
# if you have different types
data = ast.literal_eval(your_str.replace("POLYGON ",""))
x, y = data
#now you can zip the two x and y pairs together or make them into a dictionary
```

Comment: I don't understand `x, y = data` part. Will x and y be lists of strings/numbers and so using a loop I would create my dictionary ?

Also, if there are more than one Polygon defined in the string, how will I know where the first stops and the second starts ?

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: sorry the `x,y = data` part is just shorthand for `x = data[0]` and `y = data[1]`.  `x and y` will both contain the lists of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say u have a string that looks like this

my_str = 'POLYGON ((148210.445767647 172418.761192525, 148183.930888667 172366.054787545, 148183.866770629 172365.316772032, 148184.328078148 172364.737139913, 148220.543522168 172344.042601933, 148221.383518338 172343.971823159), (148221.97916844 172344.568316375, 148244.61381946 172406.651932395, 148244.578100039 172407.422441673, 148244.004662562 172407.938319453, 148211.669446582 172419.255646473, 148210.631989339 172419.018894911, 148210.445767647 172418.761192525))'

```
my_str = my_str.replace('POLYGON ', '')
coords_groups = my_str.split('), (')

for coords in coords_groups:
    coords.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    coords_list = coords.split(', ')
    coords_list2 = []
    for item in coords_list:
        item_split = item.split(' ')
        coords_list2.append({'x', item_split[0], 'y': item_split[1]})
```

I think this should help a little

All u need now is a way to get info between parenthesis, this should help [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/python-regex-help-return-text-between-parenthesis)

**UPDATE** updated code above thanks to another answer  by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2635860/mccakici , but this works only if u have structure of string as u have said in your question

Comment: I guess I could find some way to narrow the string down to a couple of what you have in `my_str`. Thanks!

Comment: If I get this right, I might strip the `POLYGON ((` part and then strip the `))` and then use my_str.split('), (') to narrow down to multiple string like you exposed in your answer. This should be right, shouldn't it ? :)

Comment: There's a syntax error at the last line `{'x', item_split[0], 'y': item_split[1]}` should be `{'x', item_split[0], 'y', item_split[1]}` (`,` instead of `:`).
It serves the purpose well but @mccakici's answer is more on the spot. Thanks for your help !