# Basic Python - Extracting Strings

Tags: python, string, recursion, extract, parentheses

I am trying to extract what's between parenthesis (including parenthesis) **recursively**.

This is my solution:

```
def paren(txt):
  if txt[1] == ")":
    return ''
  if txt[0] == "(":
    if len(txt) > 2:
        return txt[1]  + paren(txt[:1] + txt[2:])
    return txt[1]
  if len(txt) > 2:
    return paren(txt[1:])
  return ""
```

But it doesn't include any parenthesis. How can I fix it?

Example:

```
print paren("h(ello)o")
Output: (ello)
print paren("(hello)")
Output: (hello)
```

Comment: So are you trying to find the text inside the innermost set of parentheses?

Comment: Can you give an example before and after of what you want this to do?

Comment: Will there only be one set of parenthesis? What should happen here: `'(h(ello))'`?

Comment: @IanAuld let's assume there is only one set of parenthesis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

Comment: @Zee please update your question. Also what do you mean by saying 'extract what's between parenthesis recursively`? If there is only one set of parenthesis then I do not understand why you want to do it recursively

Comment: @Zee assuming there is only one pair of parenthesis check my solution

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single pair of parenthesis, I would recommend to go with [Halcyon Abraham Ramirez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774461/halcyon-abraham-ramirez). Otherwise, try this method:

```
def paren(text):
    pstack = 0
    start = 0
    end = len(text)
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        if c == '(':
            if pstack == 0:
                start = i
            pstack += 1
        elif c == ')':
            pstack -= 1
            if pstack == 0:
                end = i
                break

    return text[start:end]
```

And here is an example:

```
>>> paren("h(ello)")
'(ello)'
```

If you do not need the root parenthesis, you can modify the return statement like this:

```
return text[start+1:end-1]
```

And again:

```
>>> paren("h(ello)")
'ello'
```

Answer (score 2):

use `index`

```
word = "hehlllllllll(ooooo)jejejeje"

def extract(word):
    return word[word.index("("):word.index(")") + 1]
```

output:

```
(ooooo)
```

taking it further.
if there are multiple parenthesis:

```
a = "h((el(l))o"

def extract_multiple_parenthesis(word):
    closing_parenthesis = word[::-1].index(")")
    last_parenthesis_index = (len(word) - closing_parenthesis)
    return  word[word.index("("):last_parenthesis_index]
```

output:

```
((el(l))
```

Comment: @n9code op mentioned about having only one set of parenthesis. so this solution should suffice

Comment: already removed my comment :) just noticed [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704502/basic-python-extracting-strings/31704715#comment51348150_31704502)

Comment: @n9code it's all cool :D