# Store all characters between parentheses in string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a string

```
statement = 'P ∧ (Q ∨ R) ↔ (P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ R)'
```

I want to store each string that is within parentheses, like this:

```
['Q ∨ R', 'P ∧ Q', 'P ∧ R']
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I saw that one, I thought this was different because I asked for a list of every string between parentheses

Comment: Exactly, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31343831/3832970.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that answer

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import re
>>> [s[1:-1] for s in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', 'P ∧ (Q ∨ R) ↔ (P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ R)')]
['Q ∨ R', 'P ∨ Q', 'P ∧ R']
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a good use-case for regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', statement)
['Q ∨ R', 'P ∧ Q', 'P ∧ R']
```

The `?` character in the pattern is a *non-greedy modifier suffix*.

Comment: I like the settle difference between finding what's inside the `()` without needing to strip it off later.