# Use numbers in a string input, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to export and use numbers in a string in Python 3.

for example

```
_input = input()
>? circle(5)
```

I want to export and use 5 as float here.

I tried to use _input.split('circle(') but it makes a list with 2 elements ['', '5)']
I tried to use _input.split(')') an, it makes another list with 2 elemtens ['circle(5', '']

Is there any module that helps me to do it or I should use split in another way ?

After this, what if I want to use 2 numbers ?

for example

```
_input = input()
>? circle(5,3.14)
```

or

```
_input = input()
>? circle(5, 3.14)
```

and then multiply this numbers ( 5 * 3.14 )

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm tired. But I don't follow at all what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Vallentin Im trying to make a shape calculator, I want user enter the shape name and numbers like this

Comment: If you want to create some sort of calculator, you'll either need a syntax parser (not so easy) or somehow implement this with `eval` (might be simpler but less clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be just one function with brackets then use this. First we extract string inside the bracket. Now it'll be easy for us to do whatever we want with the string.

```
s=input()
string_in_brack = s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
numbers = string_in_brack.split(',')
if len(numbers)>1:
    float(numbers[0]*numbers[1])
else:
    float(numbers[0])
```

String in brack function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis). What you do is you first search for the opening bracket '(' and then you slice the string till where the closing bracket is found ie ')'. Suppose string is `s='blahblah'` then `s[4:7]` will return 'bla' etc..

Comment: Thanks alot, It works good, Can u give me a resource about this part ? => `[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]`

Comment: @AlirezaAyinMehr Your welcome and check the edit and the link I attached..

Answer (score 1):

Probably regular expressions is the best alternative

```
import re
input_ = 'circle(5, 3.14)'
numbers = re.findall('\\d+[.]*\\d*', input_)
float(numbers[0]) * float(numbers[1])
```

Comment: I would parse the statement, but not search for integers

Comment: It works, can u explain me that ('\\d+[.]*\\d*', input_) ??

Comment: The regular expression should be read like:
Any digit (\\d), appearing 1 or more times (+), followed by a stop ([.]) appearing 0 or more times (*), followed by any digit (\\d) appearing 0 or more times (*)

Answer (score 1):

Hardcode-y way to parse your string:

```
>>> s = 'circle(5, 3.14)'
>>> a, b = map(float, s.strip()[7:-1].split(','))
>>> a
5.0
>>> b
3.14
>>> a*b
15.700000000000001
```

i.e. take the number part, split by comma, turn the list elements to floats and multiply them.

Using a regex might be more easily translatable to similar problems:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'circle(5, 3.14)'
>>> a, b = re.match('\s*circle\((\d(?:\.\d+)?),\s*(\d(?:\.\d+))?\)\s*', s).groups()
>>> float(a)*float(b)
15.700000000000001
```

regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/O3bSwr/1/