# need to all extract the content inside the brackets in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text-extraction, data-extraction

I need to extract only the content inside the brackets in pandas dataframe. I tried using str.exratct() but its not working . I need help with the extraction

DATA: ( IS IN DATA FRAME, This is a sample data from one row )

By:Chen TX (Chen Tianxu)[ 1 ] ; Tribbitt MA (Tribbitt Mark A.)[ 2 ] ; Yang Y (Yang Yi)[ 3 ] ; Li XM (Li Xiaomei)[ 4 ]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `regular expression`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dataset = pd.DataFrame([{'DATA': 'By:Chen TX (Chen Tianxu)[ 1 ] ; Tribbitt MA (Tribbitt Mark A.)[ 2 ] ; Yang Y (Yang Yi)[ 3 ] ; Li XM (Li Xiaomei)[ 4 ]'}])
print(dataset)
```

Dataframe is:

```
   DATA
0  By:Chen TX (Chen Tianxu)[ 1 ] ; Tribbitt MA (Tribbitt Mark A.)[ 2 ] ; Yang Y (Yang Yi)[ 3 ] ; Li XM (Li Xiaomei)[ 4 ]
```

Then, using `regular expression` with `lambda` function, such that you extract names and save it to different column named `names`:

```
# regular expression from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31343831/5916727
dataset['names'] = dataset['DATA'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\((.*?)\)',x))
print(dataset['names'])
```

Output of `names` column would be:

```
0    [Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xiaomei]
```

Comment: @venkatesh_Babu Great! you can accept the answer if you would like.  `Happy Coding.`

Comment: but how do remove the [ ] ?? can you pleased help me out . tried replace function but it didnt work

Comment: you mean you want `Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xiaomei` as single string, because right now it is list of string separated with `,`