# How would I convert user input into function arguments?

Tags: python, arrays, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make a custom command line to control a robotic arm.
So I want to be able to run the program and type in servoMove(arg1,arg2) and have arg1 and arg2 get transferred into the function servoMove.

```
servoPos = [0,1,2,3,4]

def servoMove(servo,angle):
    servoPos[servo] = angle
    print(servoPos[servo])

def commands(cmd):
    if cmd == 'servoMove('+arg1+','+arg2+')':
        servoMove(arg1,arg2)
    else:
        print("[Error] - Unknown Command")

commands(input(""))
```

Clearly, the code below doesn't work for this.

```
    if cmd == 'servoMove('+arg1+','+arg2+')':
        servoMove(arg1,arg2)
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: I'm guessing the command line interface is some kind of requirement in the brief, otherwise why wouldn't you just run the module and then in the shell prompt type "servoMove(etc"?

Comment: `"servoMove('+arg1+','+arg2+')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to parse the command.

```
import re
def commands(cmd):
    m = re.match(r'servoMove\((\d+),(\d+)\)', cmd)
    if m:
        servoMove(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)))
        return
    # Put similar tests for other commands here
    # ...
    print("[Error] - Unknown Command")
```

This is a really crude way to do it -- if the user doesn't enter the command exactly right it will complain that the command is unknown. If you want something more robust, you need to learn how to write a real parser. Or use a better user interface, such as Tkinter to implement a form that the user can fill out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cmd module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmd.html) to build a command line interface.

Here's an example:

```
import cmd

servoPos = [0,1,2,3,4]

def servoMove(servo,angle):
    servoPos[servo] = angle
    print(servoPos[servo])

class ServoShell(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = '=> '

    def do_servoMove(self, arg):
        'Edit this to give a description to the function when typing ?'
        servoMove(*parse(arg))

def parse(arg):
    'Convert a comma separated string into a tuple'
    return tuple(map(int, arg.strip('()').split(',')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServoShell().cmdloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the structure the problem is in the if statement: arg1 and arg2 are undefined at that stage, so you'll get a False. For starters you'd want to replace that with something like:

```
#Look at the nine first characters to see if they match your function
if cmd[:9] == 'servoMove':
```

To extract your arguments, I'd use some string manipulation as in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis) I've sliced the input to take the text between "(" and "," as arg1, and "," and ")" as arg2.

```
arg1 = cmd[cmd.find("(")+1:cmd.find(",")]
arg2 = cmd[cmd.find(",")+1:cmd.find(")")]
```

Putting it together:

```
def commands(cmd):
    if cmd[:9] == 'servoMove':
        arg1 = cmd[cmd.find("(")+1:cmd.find(",")]
        arg2 = cmd[cmd.find(",")+1:cmd.find(")")]
        servoMove(arg1, arg2)
    else:
        print("[Error] - Unknown Command")
```

Comment: If you're going this way, it's probably easier to use [`.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to parse the command.