# Extracting content between curly braces in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have lines of the form `{},{},{},...,{}`. The number of curly pairs is variable. I would like to have the content between the curlies in a list of strings.

Example:

Input: `{a:b,c:d}`

Output: `['a:b,c:d']`

---

Input: `{a:b,c:d},{e:f,g:h}`

Output: `['a:b,c:d', 'e:f,g:h']`

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Use `re.findall()`.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: What more is there to explain? You write a regexp that matches something inside braces, and use `re.findall` to get a list of all the matches.

Comment: I can't explain any more without writing the code in full. But you're the programmer, not me.

Comment: Regex sounds like a good choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', text)
```

example:

```
>>> text = '{a:b,c:d},{e:f,g:h}'
>>> re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', text)
['a:b,c:d', 'e:f,g:h']
```

Comment: This will include the braces in the results. You need to use lookarounds so they're matched but not returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = '{a:b,c:d},{e:f,g:h}'
[e.strip('{}') for e in i.split('},{')]
# ['a:b,c:d', 'e:f,g:h']
```

Comment: And what happens if e.g. there is a space after some of the commas?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to extracting **content between "nth" set of braces** in Python - its a simple extension of the above:

```
import re
qstring="""CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Time_Table]"""

contents_inside_barckets=re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', qstr)
```

Initial output:

```
['dbo', 'Time_Table']
```

Contents of the **second** (index =1) set of brackets:

```
contents_inside_barckets[1]
```

Output

```
'Time_Table'
```