# Retrieve first word in parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, parentheses

I googled and read up on some codes here [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

but say for example I have the following string

"[Guide] Strength (STR) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"

How would I output "STR" only and not (Warriors -> Berserker) ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you actually mean the word in the first pair of parentheses, not the first word in parentheses; otherwise it would include `Warriors` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[Guide] Strength (STR) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"
>>> re.search(r'\(([^)]+)\)', s).group(1)
<<< 'STR'
```

`re.search` returns the first match
`.group(1)` returns the contents of the first capture group, which is `([^)]+)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following string,

```
s = 'I am John (John (M) Doe)'
```

The first word within valid parentheses should be 'John (M) Doe' and not 'John (M'. The following code would keep count of the open and closed parentheses:

```
opn = 0
close = 0
new_str = ''
add = False
for i in s:
    if not add:
        if i == '(':
            opn += 1
            add = True
    else:
        if i == '(':
            new_str += i
            opn += 1
        elif i == ')':
            close += 1
            if opn == close:
                break
            else:
                new_str += i
        else:
            new_str += I

print(new_str)
```

This yields:

```
John (M) Doe
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or `re.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="[Guide] Strength (STR) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"
>>> result = re.split(r"\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))", s)
>>> next((i[1:-1] for i in result if i[0]=='(' and i[-1]==')'),'No sub-strings that are surrounded by parenthesis')
'STR'
>>>
```

Note: here if the strings does not contain any sub-string surrounded by parenthesis, it will Output `'No sub-strings that are surrounded by parenthesis'`, if that's not needed you can just do:

```
>>> next((i[1:-1] for i in result if i[0]=='(' and i[-1]==')'))
```

Or:

```
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in result if i[0]=='(' and i[-1]==')'][0]
```

Comment: this also only works if the text in parentheses that you want to extract contains no whitespace characters

Comment: @KingRadical How about now?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str1 = "[Guide] Strength (STR) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"
m = re.findall(r'(\(\w+\))',str1)
print m

Result:['(STR)']
```

Here the string we need to find in given text is located between ( ) with no spaces and special charecters,So ( \w+ ) means more than one charecters present in ( )

Comment: Hi, above comment was the part from "Review" in stack over flow. I am not looking for your answer. I was just reviewing the quality of code. It is good practice to add some explanation. You can edit your answer and and can add the comments.

Comment: @Harsha B thanks for the suggestion,next time this reminds me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.search` with group as explained by @KingRadical or use `re.findall` and then select the first element.

```
s = "[Guide] Strength (STR  are long) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"
re.findall('\(([^\)]+)\)', s) # returns all matches

>>> ['STR  are long', 'Warriors -> Berserker']

re.findall('\(([^\)]+)\)', s)[0] # returns the first match which is what you want.

>>> 'STR  are long'
```

**Note:**

If there is no match in the string **s**, `re.findall` will return an empty **list** while `re.search` will return a `None` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string with indices returned by `str.find`:

```
s = "[Guide] Strength (STR) is recommended on Warriors (Warriors -> Berserker)"
s[s.find('(')+1:s.find(')')]
```

which returns: `STR`