# Error in regular expression to find the text between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
string  ='((clearance) AND (embedded) AND (software engineer OR developer)) AND (embedded)'
```

I want to break into lists based on the parenthesis, so referring [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis) given I have used

```
my_data = re.findall(r"(\(.*?\))",string)
```

but when I print my_data, the output is (len = 4)

```
['((clearance)', '(embedded)', '(software engineer OR developer)', '(embedded)']
```

but my desired output is (len = 2)

```
['(clearance) AND (embedded) AND (software engineer OR developer)', '(embedded)']
```

because "(clearance) AND (embedded) AND (software engineer OR developer)" is in one parenthesis and "embedded" is in another parenthesis. but the "re.findall" is breaking in 4 lists, why?

If I want my desired output, how to modify the regular expression?

Comment: If it weren't for python you could've used [RegEx recursion](https://regex101.com/r/OWzBKh/1/) without a problem, but python doesn't support that per default (i believe). You could try and install [this](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and see if you can get the pattern from my first link to work that way, but i can't promise anything (I'm not that familiar with python).

Comment: Will the depth of `()` will always be two or can be higher ?

Comment: its random, it can be multiple.

Comment: You want to match balanced parenthesis

Comment: With an unclear amount of parenthesis, this can *not* be done with pure regex. Refer to this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8408080

Comment: @user8408080 it can be done easily if balanced parenthesis is not necessary.

Comment: is there any other way to detect the patterns or should I write the program manually to count open and closed parenthesis ?

Comment: I think writing your own parser for this is not hard, you just need one counter. Remember the index where the counter goes from 0 to 1 and remember the index where the counter goes from 1 to 0. There you have your positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure regex, this would not be possible, so here is an idea that counts parenthesis:

```
def find_stuff(string):
    indices = []
    counter = 0
    change = {"(":1, ")":-1}
    for i, el in enumerate(string):
        new_count = counter + change.get(el, 0)
        if counter==0 and new_count==1:
            indices.append(i)
        elif counter==1 and new_count==0:
            indices.append(i+1)
        counter = new_count
    return indices
```

This is not very beautiful, but I think the concept is clear. It returns the indices of outer parenthesis, so you can just slice your string with these

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Though I really didn't understand what "change" is doing.

Comment: I used the dict as a quick way to count parenthesis. I always add `change[el]` to the `counter`. If `el` is a `(`, I this adds a `1`, meaning, that there is one unclosed bracket. If `el` is `)` it adds `-1`, effectively saying, that there is a closing bracket, so i'm one level down. The `get` function takes a default argument, so if `el` is neither `(` nor `)`, the current "deepness level" is changed by `0`, so not at all

Comment: great got it now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an `re` hack, but this is possible:

```
>>> string  ='((clearance) AND (embedded) AND (software engineer OR developer)) AND (embedded)'
>>> [e for e in re.split(r'\((?=\()(.*?)(?<=\))\)|(?<!\()(\([^()]+\))(?!\))',string) if e and '(' in e and ')' in e]
['(clearance) AND (embedded) AND (software engineer OR developer)', '(embedded)']
```