# Python regular expressions - split a string on some values but not all

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a function to split a list of names.

```
name_ex = 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)'

split_name =re.split('\. |, | ', name_ex)
last_name = split_name[0]
title = split_name[1]
other_names = split_name[2:]
```

The output when I print split_name is below

```
['Futrelle', 'Mrs', 'Jacques', 'Heath', '(Lily', 'May', 'Peel)']
```

However what I want to achieve is:

```
['Futrelle', 'Mrs', 'Jacques', 'Heath', 'Lily May Peel']
```

Any idea how I would achieve this?

Additional context
- Some names don't have the additional name in brackets
- All names are in the order last name, title, first name (middle name optional), bracketed name

Comment: Follow this tutorial. There are several ways to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894156/9686651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match groups in parenthesis and then subsequent runs of characters:

```
import re
name_ex = 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)'
new_data = re.findall('(?<=\()[\w\s]+(?=\))|\w+', name_ex)
```

Output:

```
['Futrelle', 'Mrs', 'Jacques', 'Heath', 'Lily May Peel']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
import re

name_ex = 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)'
m = re.match(r"(?P<lname>[A-Za-z]+), (?P<title>[A-Za-z]+)\. (?P<fname>[A-Za-z]+)(?P<mname>[\sA-Za-z]+)? \((?P<bname>.*?)\)", name_ex)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

**Output:**

```
('Futrelle', 'Mrs', 'Jacques', ' Heath', 'Lily May Peel')
```