# How to read/choose only a part of the input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read an input which might have some information that I do not need for my program and for example I need only the part in brackets, how can I omit/eliminate that unneeded part? Just a simple example would be:

```
S={[2,5],[3,4],[5,6]}
```

So how can I omit everything and only take from the input [2,5] [3,4] and [5,6]?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried already? You may want to consider regex (regular expressions).

Comment: I tried reading the whole input as a string and sort only the parts that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your string is that:

```
S="{[2,5],[3,4],[5,6]}"

print(S[S.find("{")+1:S.find("}")])
```

will return the substring inside the parenthesis  `'[2,5],[3,4],[5,6]'`

Considering other options, I based my answer in the accepted one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you data to be a string and similar to 
`S={[2,5],[3,4],[5,6]}`
the noticeable thing is the `{` and `}`
are in the position 0 and n-1 of the string ,n being the length of string 
you may use

```
 S={[2,5],[3,4],[5,6]}
print(S[1:-1])
```

where S[:] refer `S[to begin with :to end ]`
as we want to omit data at pos 0 we begin with 1 and the last element '}' we use [1:-1]
where -1  refers to last position similarly -2 will be second last and so on