# Retreive the first bracket content using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as

```
str='[dbo].[AGENTS]'
```

I want to retreive only first bracket value using regular expression how can I do that

output :
dbo

Comment: no need to use regex. just use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis
replace the parentheses with brackets

Comment: If you decide to do regex, than, possibly [`[^][]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dU42kT/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using groups:

```
test_string = '[dbo].[AGENTS]'
pattern = "\[(\w+)\].\[(\w+)\]"
match = re.match(pattern, test_string)
print(match.group(1))
```

### Output

```
dbo
```