# Get the string within brackets and remove useless string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this `'0x69313430303239377678(i1400297vx)'` I only want the value `i1400297vx` and nothing else.

Is there a simple way for example using `strip` method or I'm forced to use Regex,I'm not good at...

Someone could kindly help me?

Comment: use split("()") ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Comment: @billz `'0x69313430303239377678(i1400297vx)'.split("()")` returns `['0x69313430303239377678(i1400297vx)']` - this is **not what OP wants**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, using split and strip:

```
'0x69313430303239377678(i1400297vx)'.split('(')[1].strip(')')
```

but a regex would be more readable!