# How do I extract the contents of a string within a parenthesis?

Tags: python, discord.py

lets say I have an on_message event that sees if the message has "pick crocka"

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if "pick crocka" in message.content.lower():
```

I want him to pick the part in the message where 2 or more stuff are inside parentheses, split with ,s likes this:

> > pick crocka, do you like pizza with pinapple? (i like it, i hate
> it)
>
> > hmmm, id say i hate it

(note that he would pick stuff randomly, I know the random.choice() part, all I need is how I can take only the part inside parentheses

Comment: Sorry man but your explanation is really confusing. Could you rephrase it in another way?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
import re
message = """pick crocka, do you like pizza with pinapple? (i like it, i hate it)"""
options = re.search(r'\(.*?\)', message).group(0)[1:-1].split(", ")
print(options)
```

output:

```
['i like it', 'i hate it']
```

Comment: thanks alot my friend