# Removing Specific Substrings from String Used for Data Slice

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string where I need to keep two key numbers and remove the rest which need to be converted to a string that can be used to slice data.

```
sample = 'range(0, 286)range(300, 511)'
```

I will always need the first two numbers (ex. `0 and 286`). Each of these numbers will not always be `0 and 286`. They can have multiple positions like `10 and 1000` or `100 and 10000`. They will always be in parentheses and have a comma to separate each number. The second set of numbers do not need to be extracted from the string.

**Expected Output:** My end product would be a string that looks like a slice:

```
print([sample])
[0:286]
```

How do I extract just the first two numbers from this text, zero and two-hundred-eighty-six?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `f"""{[sample[sample.find("(")+1:sample.find(")")].replace(' ','')]}"""`, addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the following input:

```
series = pd.Series(['range(0, 286)range(300, 511)', 'range(100, 1000)range(300, 511)'])
```

you can use `str.extract` with named groups:

```
series.str.extract('range\((?P<number1>\d+),\s+(?P<number2>\d+)\)')
```

output:

```
  number1 number2
0       0     286
1     100    1000
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, however looks like the question does not need pandas based on the input/output expected. though it is tagged.

Comment: it was an accident, ill reup in five minutes