# extract multiple argument with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to define a new Google Sheet formula using Google Script (which have Javascript grammar if I understand it well).

so, given myformula

```
=MYFORMULA(A1;A2;A3;A4;A5;A6;B7)
```

I found how to extract all the arguments [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281590/6564973)

```
function myFormula(arguments)
{
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  //var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var extr = formula.match(/\(([^()]+)\)/).pop();
  return extr;
}

--> extr = "A1;A2;A3;A4;A5;A6;B7"
```

i would like to extract the list of all arguments (assuming ";" as separator)
and eventually discard the last one, obtaining something like

```
extr = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"];
```

How can I do with a regex? Single regex or with iteration? (number of items is variable)

Comment: Try replacing your return statement with`return extr.split(';').slice(0, -1)` - `extr.split(';')` gets you `["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "B7"]` and `.slice(0, -1)` ditches the last element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the answer was taken from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

As mentioned by [@Hao Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10289265/hao-wu), the return statement can contain an operation that would split the value to get the desired output:

```
function myFormula(arguments)
{
...

  var extr = formula.match(/\(([^()]+)\)/).pop();
  return extr.split(',').slice(0, -1);
}
```

[image]